# Itunes connect doesn't detect app ID

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect

I want to add a new app to the app store, they ask me a name and SKU number and than I have to select your app ID.

When I select the app ID to make the new app, I can't find the app ID that I need. I can only find those that I never used.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you made an app ID for AppStore publishing?

Comment: And you can only create one App per bundle Identifier, so of course you can only find those that you've never used.

Comment: yes I followed a steps of publishing app in AppStore, I first time was able to see my ID but I refreshed the browser to try again then it has been disappeared.

Comment: I never used the new App ID.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but a case for customer support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wait for sometime. This is apple server issue.

I faced this same issue last day.

Comment: I afraid that it has been disappeared forever because the first wrong selection because first time I was able to see my ID but I refreshed the browser because it hangs and to try again then it has been disappeared. :S

Comment: No it will work dont worry.

After application metadata uploading itunes remove the bundle identifier from the list.

Comment: How Long I have to wait?

Comment: Cant Say.. may be few minute or a day

Comment: Working now? I hope it is

Comment: unfortunately not work .. I created a new AppID. :( .. but thanks so much for your answer. :)